# O script carrega antes do ng-view ter carregado (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, aplicação-web, front-end

Estou com problemas com a seguinte situação: eu tenho um **ng-view** na minha página, mas preciso que dois scripts que eu implemento no final da página **esperem** o meu **ng-view** carregar para que eles interajam com as classes dos elementos dentro do meu ng-view. São os scripts "*scrollreveal.js*" e "*magnific-popup.min.js*" **Código abaixo**:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>



<!--Core JS-->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--AngularJS-->
<script src="app/AngularJS/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/AngularJS/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<!--App-->
<script src="app/app.js"></script>

<!--Routes-->
<script src="app/routes.js"></script>

<!--Directives-->
<!--<script src="app/directives/frameworks-directive.js"></script>-->

<!--Controllers-->

<!--Frameworks JS-->
<script src="js/scrollreveal.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/creative.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após especificar seu `controller` no `$routeProvider`, use o controller para carregar os scripts. No caso, tire-os do `body`:

```
app.controller('yourCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.load = function() {
       var script1 = document.createElement('script');
       var script2 = document.createElement('script');
       script1.type = 'text/javascript';
       script2.type = 'text/javascript';
       script1.src = "js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js";
       script2.src = "js/scrollreveal.js";
       document.body.appendChild(script1);
       document.body.appendChild(script2);
   };
   $scope.load();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Se você não definir as dependências de um módulo na criação dele ou em blocos de configuração, o Angular vai carregar os scripts de maneira assíncrona, não garantido que a sequência desejada seja seguida.

Veja [esse link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/dependency-injection.html#minification-safe-dependency-injection) para entender como isso funciona e implementar no seu código.

Comment: Boa referência.

Comment: Curti muito a referência e agradeço muito pela ajuda. Vou usar como fonte de consulta. Por questão de pressa, acabei usando a solução do @SamirBraga, que acabou dando certo.